# How to open new stage and close previous stage between classes

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8, stage

I try to open new stage and close previous stage between classes but i couldn't success in javafx. maybe if we use singleton pattern , it can run successfully. when you press button , first window will close and second window open.

Here is code;

First class:

```
 public class First extends Application {

   public  Stage primaryStage2,primaryStage3;

  Second v=new Second();

     @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Press");

this.primaryStage3=primaryStage;

btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

      v.open();
    }
   });

StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(btn);      
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
 }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
  }


         }
```

Second class :

```
   public class Second {

 Stage  primaryStage2;

   First a=new First();

 public void open(){

  primaryStage2=new Stage();
 StackPane root = new StackPane();              
 Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);       
primaryStage2.setScene(scene);
 a.primaryStage3.close();
primaryStage2.show();
 }
}
```

Comment: I do not recomend the usage of singleton, only in very specific situations, and when there is no other solution, I use this pattern.

Comment: please indent the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to create new Stage? You can easily create different scenes as you need. And change the scene as you require.

> Try the code below

Main class

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
public class Main extends Application 
{    
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
Button btn=new Button("Click Here");
Stage primaryStage;
Scene scene ;
public Main()
{
    btn.setPrefWidth(75);
    btn.setPrefHeight(15);

    btn.setOnAction((e)->
    {
        SubClass s=new SubClass(primaryStage);
    });
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    try {
        this.primaryStage=primaryStage;
        //          root.getChildren().add(btn);

        scene = initStage();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Scene initStage()
{
    root.setCenter(btn);
    return new Scene(root,150,150);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

> Sub Class

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SubClass
{

StackPane root = new StackPane();
Stage stage;

public SubClass(Stage stage)
{
    Scene scene=new Scene(root,300,300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

> I would suggest you to try changing the scene rather than the stage. All the best

Answer (score 0):

try this one for login and open a new window

```
   package signIn;
  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
  import javafx.event.EventHandler;
  import javafx.geometry.Insets;
  import javafx.geometry.Pos;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
  import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
  import javafx.scene.control.Button;
  import javafx.scene.control.Label;
  import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
  import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
  import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

  public class JavaFXWindowDemo extends Application {

  private String loggedInUser;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  // How to open a new window in JavaFX
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
  Button btnLogin = new Button();
  btnLogin.setText("Login");
  btnLogin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        showLoginScreen();
    }
 });
 // A layout container for UI controls
 StackPane root = new StackPane();
 root.getChildren().add(btnLogin);

 // Top level container for all view content
 Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

// primaryStage is the main top level window created by platform
primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Demo");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
}

public void setLoggedInUser(String user) {
loggedInUser = user;

Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.setTitle("Successful login");
alert.setHeaderText("Successful login");
String s = user + " logged in!";
alert.setContentText(s);
alert.show();
}

public void showLoginScreen() {
Stage stage = new Stage();

VBox box = new VBox();
box.setPadding(new Insets(10));

// How to center align content in a layout manager in JavaFX
box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

Label label = new Label("Enter username and password");

TextField textUser = new TextField();
textUser.setPromptText("enter user name");
TextField textPass = new TextField();
textPass.setPromptText("enter password");

Button btnLogin = new Button();
btnLogin.setText("Login");

btnLogin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // Assume success always!
        setLoggedInUser(textUser.getText());
        stage.close(); // return to main window
    }
});

box.getChildren().add(label);
box.getChildren().add(textUser);
box.getChildren().add(textPass);
box.getChildren().add(btnLogin);
Scene scene = new Scene(box, 250, 150);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void get(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {

       Parent home_page = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("anotherpage.fxml"));
        Stage app = (Stage)((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        app.setScene(new Scene(home_page,300, 275));
        app.show();
}
```

Comment: thats will help u bro just give method to button then when u click on it will open another page (use it with scene builder fxml)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems to be here:

```
 public class Second {

 Stage  primaryStage2;

 First a=new First();

 public void open(){

  primaryStage2=new Stage();
 StackPane root = new StackPane();              
 Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);       
primaryStage2.setScene(scene);
 a.primaryStage3.close();
primaryStage2.show();
 }
}
```

There you are creating a new First and then getting the stage of that NEW first and closing it, that is to say, that the one that was previously open, its actually another object.

Your action probably needs to do something more like this:

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

      v.open();
primaryStage3.close(); // new LINE!!
    }
   });
```

That is to say, close the stage from the button action, and not from showing the other window, because that will cause the two objects to be unnecessarily coupled.

I would also recomend using diferent classes for the application itself, and the windows that you want to show. Right now thats not a problem, but when your app grows in size, it will turn into one.
When having a class for each different window, each one of these could hold thir Stage, just as your Second class does right not, but with out repeating unnecessarily those references in the Application class.